# Disable user registration email in Joomla 3.5

Tags: joomla

In Joomla 3.5 I would like to disable the email a user will get if he registers. I have a setup where a user can register himself to my site. However the user always gets an email with registration. I would like to disable this however can not find the proper place.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: @ Shaz I found this post before. The post deals with the fact that the admin registers the user. My post deals with the case when the user registers himself. This is not the same and the solution in your post is not working here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the guilty code is located at:
[/components/com_users/models/registration.php](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_users/models/registration.php#L538) line 538 (Joomla! 3.5.1).

```
// Send the registration email.
$return = JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($data['mailfrom'], $data['fromname'], $data['email'], $emailSubject, $emailBody);
```

There is no condition at all that would avoid this line by any means.

Probably the only option you've got is to override the com_users component:
https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

Use the [Mvc override plugin](https://github.com/ghazal/plg_mvcoverride), even if it's not that stable, it should do the job.